# StringReader or Memory Stream which is resource friendly?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a module which will be responsible for parsing CSV data received from different user via a website interface, and I have to parse that CSV. I was considering to use, `TextFieldParser` for it.

But before I could implement I was considering what shall be a better approach...

1. Generating `MemoryStream` from data received,
2. or initialising a `StringReader` from the same input string.

Which one is better & why?

Comment: Got a similar question, using `DataContractSerializer`, I'm curious to know which one is more efficient: `using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml)))` or `using (var backing = new StringReader(xml)) using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(backing))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1 won't give you a string at all, so if you want to work with a byte array and buffers, go that way but it seems unlikely.  If you're doing string processing would strongly recommend Option 2, because with that you can read a line at a time.

As far as I can see the only reason to use a `MemoryStream` would be if you need to do something more complex that `StringReader` doesn't handle as you want (otherwise you're reinventing the wheel): encodings, strange line formats, etc.

Having worked with very large files (specifically CSV files) with `StringReader`s, I've never had a problem.  I'd wager that when MS designed `StringReader` to do exactly what you're trying to do, they made it as resource-friendly as possible.

Comment: I have to pass this new object to TextFieldParser which accepts Stream or TextReader, I was looking to resource efficient way of doing this, no reinvention of wheel there! :)

Comment: In which case, don't use either, pass the `TextFieldParser` the filename directly, as in the MSDN documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx#Y1795

Comment: there is a requirement that data can be passed via contents pasted to TextArea directly... no file uploads... to pass file name there I have to save that to some temporary file on my server, so I was kind of looking for other options ... but now I think that can be done!